# Set width and height of image input type ="file" in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, file, input, onload, input-type-file

I want to set a specific width and height of the uploaded image.
I am able to take the size of the uplaoded image, but don't really understand how should i limit it, when uploading.

```
        $scope.img = new Image();
        $scope.changeSelectedImage = function (element) {
            $scope.reader.onload = function () {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.questionImgSrc = $scope.reader.result;
                    $scope.img.src = $scope.questionImgSrc;
                    $scope.img.onload = function() {
                        // access image size here
                        angular.element("#" + $scope.inputFileId).attr('width', $scope.img.width);
                        console.log($scope.img.width);
                        console.log($scope.img.height);
                    };
                });

            };
```